# Dropdown controls get higher precedence in visibility when overlapped by any other control on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a css and javascript based horizental menu bar in master Page.
I have a content page which has multiple textbox and dropdownlist.

the problem is that when i run this page in mozila it runs successfull but when i run it in IE than horizental menu list items is overlapped by dropdownlist means dropdownlist hide the horizental menu item. this problem is happen with only dropdownlist not with textboxes

so please tell me how to resolve this problem

sorry for english

Answer (score 1):

The usual fix for this is to place an iframe behind your menu bar. The iframe is one of the few elements that has priority over a drop down list in older version of IE. The iframe should obscure the drop down list and you can pop your menu over the top of it.

It isn't a nice solution, but this is the technique I have used many times to deal with this IE specific problem.

UPDATE

Here is a quick example of an iframe shim using JavaScript...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        #overthetop {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 5px;
            background-color: Yellow;
            z-index: 1000;
        }


        #myiframe {
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="iframeshim">
        <iframe src="about:blank" id="myiframe"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="overthetop">
        <p>Some</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Here</p>
    </div>
    <select name="test"><option value="test">Test</option></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var overTheTop = document.getElementById("overthetop");
        var iframeShim = document.getElementById("iframeshim");
        var myIframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");

        var w = overTheTop.offsetWidth;
        var h = overTheTop.offsetHeight;
        var t = overTheTop.top;
        var l = overTheTop.left;

        iframeShim.style.display = "block";
        iframeShim.style.position = "absolute";
        iframeShim.style.top = t + "px";
        iframeShim.style.left = l + "px";
        iframeShim.style.width = w + "px";
        iframeShim.style.height = h + "px";
        iframeShim.style.zindex = "900";

        myIframe.style.width = w + "px";
        myIframe.style.height = h + "px";

        overTheTop.style.zIndex = "1000";


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please send me how to use iframe in master-content page context.

Comment: till now i hanven't use iframe

Comment: Example added... it is quite a verbose example, but it should demonstrate the fix - try it in the IE version you have the problem in!